# My service modules not recognised by dask

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I have a service with in I have several modules and in the main file I am importing most of my modules like below.

```
from base_client import BaseClient
import request_dispatcher as rd
import utils as util
```

In one of the functions in main I am calling the dask client submit. When I try to get the result back from future object it give me modulenotfound error as below

****ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'base_client'****

This is how I define my client and call the function

```
def mytask(url, dest):
   .....

client = Client(<scheduler ip>)
f_obj = client.submit(mytask, data_url, destination)
```

How exactly can I make these modules available to scheduler and workers?

Answer (score 1):

When you do `submit`, Dask wraps up your task and sends it to the worker(s). As part of this package, any variables that are required by the task are serialised and sent too. In the case of functions defined inline, this includes the whole function, but in the case of functions in a module, it is only the module and function names. This is done to same CPU and bandwidth (imagine trying to send all the source of all of the modules you happen to have imported).
On the worker side, the task is unwrappd, and for the function, this means importing the module, `import base_client`. This follows the normal python logic of looking in the locations defined by `sys.path`. If the file defining the module isn't there, you get the error above.

To solve, copy the file to a place that the worker can see it. You can do this with `upload_file` on a temporary basis (which uses a temporary directory), but you would be better installing the module using usual `pip` or `conda` methods. Importing from the "current directory" is likely to fail even with a local cluster.

To get more information, you would need to post a complete example, which shows the problem. In practice, functions using imports from modules are used all the time with `submit` without problems.

Comment: That is good explanation. I will try with upload_file